# Get only documents in a FireBase collection that have an id matching with documents in a separate collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following database structure:

```
users
 |_____user01
          |_____groups
                   |_____0002
                   |_____0004
                   |_____0006
groups
 |_____0001
 |_____0002
 |_____0003
 |_____0004
 |_____0005
 |_____0006
```

I currently have a StreamBuilder() that creates a list with **all** the entries it finds in *root/groups*, so it creates a list of 6 elements.

I need it to create a list using the entries in *root/groups* as it's doing now, but only those that have an id that matches the IDs of entries present in *root/users/user01/groups*, so it should create a list with 3 elements (0002, 0004 and 0006).

I can't wrap my head around how to achieve that.

This is my StreamBuild() :

```
StreamBuilder(

              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("groups").snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshots) {
                if (snapshots.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshots.data.documents.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                        snapshots.data.documents[index];
                        return Dismissable( 
                          child: Card(
                            )
)
```

Should I make a firebase query using ***where()*** that excludes documents IDs not shared by the two collections and feed the results to the StreamBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a `FutureBuilder` for every `document` inside the list you are creating using `StreamBuilder` and rendering using `ListView.builder`.

Create a future that matches each and every document in the list with documents inside the sub-collection of user i.e, `groups`.

```
Future<bool> matchDocs(String id)async{
    
    
    final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).collection('groups').doc(id).get();
    
    return result.exists;
  }
```

Inside itemBuilder function return a `FutureBuilder`.

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream:
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("groups").snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshots) {
                if (snapshots.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshots.data.documents.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                            snapshots.data.documents[index];
                        return FutureBuilder<bool>(
                            future: matchDocs(
                                snapshots.data.documents[index].data()['id'].toString()),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                if (snapshot.data) {
                                  return Dismissible(key: null, child: null);
                                }
                              }
                             return Container();
                            } 
                         );
                      }
                   );
                }
              }
 )
```

> Note: I did not have any idea about your exact data models, so you
> should be careful while implementing this solution.

Comment: Thank you so much Asad, I'll try that asap.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but the list renders correctly only if the documents in root/groups are the exact same number and ids of the documents that are in root/users/user01/groups, otherwise I get this error:
A build function returned null.

The offending widget is: FutureBuilder<bool>
Build functions must never return null.

To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".

Comment: I swear to god I tried to return the Container exactly as you did before answering here but for some reason it wasn't working, but now it does hahah.
Thank you so much you are my hero :)

Comment: Sometimes when you're so much drowned in work it's hard to notice little glitches in code .
Glad that it worked :)